# how to make div shadow only in belly part of box - css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

how is this possible in css? i saw some jsfiddle code but they seem to be pretty complex.

can someone pls help me?

Comment: Isn't it easier just to use box-shadow? That's what it was designed for.

Comment: @JoshC, but box shadows dont do this what i want. i need this vertical curve shadow

Comment: You could just use an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="box effect">
    <h3>Effect</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}
.effect
{
    position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
       -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
            box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}
.effect:before, .effect:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect:after
{
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
       -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
        -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
         -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
            transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sewjV/)**

Answer (score 1):

check out this pages, [CSS drop-shadows without images](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/)
[Creating Different CSS3 Box Shadows Effects](http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects)

This may help.